# Changing Javascript and CSS File Paths Automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, plugins

I am organizing my css and javascript files in may project. I have a lot of file and it is hard to organize the files.

When I drag and drop the css and javascript files to another folder, I must change file references in html files.

Is there any plugin for visual studio? When I drag and drop a css or javascript file to another folder, plugin can change file path in html file automatically.

Please help about this problem. If there is a plugin that does these processes, it will ease my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot imagine why you would be constantly changing the location of static files? The answer here is simply to stop doing that. Make a folder, maybe "assets" and within that folder "img, js, and css" and then simply leave those files alone :)

Something like grunt, compiling, minifying, saving and then changing paths could be done in concept, but again the labour to pull that off for no reason I can possible imagine, seems crazy.

UPDATE: It also occurred to me that you might use something like GLOB to scan the directory with the folders to ascertain the highest numbered folder, something similar to:

```
$glob           = glob("path/to/css/*");
$highestCssFile = max(preg_replace("|[^0-9]|", "", $glob));
```

Then you'd simply use $highestCssFile in your file path.

Also something like this could work to find the latest directory:

```
$cssDir= scandir("uploads/",1);
rsort($cssDir);
$latestDir = $cssDir[0];
$newDir = $latestDir+1;
```

Comment: OK, that's at least an explanation :) Although I never heard of a development process quite like that. What I CAN recommend is that you look into versioning (subversion or git) and work that way. If you are working as a team, perhaps remotely, I can also recommend http://beanstalkapp.com/ as a friendly introduction to those technologies that also add a layer of team communication.

Comment: We are coding a big project as a team. At begin, our css and js files are in a folder like assets. But at this file structure, it is hard to find a file. We want to organize these file according to version number. For example, I have css and js files that they version number is "1.2". Folder number is going to be "1.2" and I want to carry css and js files to related version number folder. Again css files and js files are going to be under different folder separately in "1.2" folder.

Comment: I understand, I just don't see that structure as maintainable or realistically scalable. If you used subversion you would simply "tag" the files as "version 1.2" etc as you proceed, with the ability to track every change made, revert, branch and all the other bonuses that come with a proper versioning system.

Putting files in differently names folders is just not the way to do it I'm afraid.

Since however grunt (http://gruntjs.com/) could actually accomplish this for you automatically (and more, albeit with tricky setup) I'd appreciate being marked the correct answer :)

Comment: As I understand, Grunt sends js or css files to under related folder, right? When I write code for GruntFile,                                                                                        eg. dist: { src: ['src/**/*.js'], dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js' }                            above code means js files into dist folder and dist folder imports related js files to user interface file (like HTML). If I am wrong, please fix me.

Comment: Yes something similar to that, you can also look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-assets-versioning. However my (edited) answer containing (untested) code to scan your directories for the latest files/folders, does solve your immediate problem I think, so again the correct answer points would be appreciated...and now back to my day job! :)

Comment: It could be solve my problem partially. As far as I read the documentation of gruntjs, It is great. If I can not use it on all my problem, I will definetely use it for other things. Thanks for your answer. I am hopeful about gruntjs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugins to do exactly what you want, but you could use ASP.NET's [bundling and minification](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms/) to reduce your changes to a single file.